# Problems with installing phpMyAdmin

Tags: 16.04, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I Installed phpMyAdmin (Ubuntu 16.04) and the installation failed. Initially I accidentally named the phpmyadmin table to 'test', and after reinstalling phpmyadmin with another table name (phpmyadmin), it keeps looking for 'test' even though it doesn't exist:

```
#1146 - Table 'test.pma__tracking' doesn't exist
```

I tried to purge phpmyadmin and reinstall it, and it keeps looking for this test table...

any solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055394/1146-table-phpmyadmin-pma-tracking-doesnt-exist

Comment: That's great but.. I don't want the database to be called 'test'... is there any way of changing it?